# MongoDB Replica Set Member State is "OTHER"

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

Three members, primary & secondary - and a third one that's "OTHER" - I can't find any info on that state, not sure what to do, I've restarted the instance, but it always comes-up the same. Can find no documentation on that state.

I'm new to replica sets - and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry - version is 3.4.3 running on Ubuntu 1604

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity - the problem is that the instance can't sync with the primary or secondary because it was down too long. It goes into a state of trying primary and secondary, over-and-over, never being allowed to sync. This eventually created an 8GB log file, which I couldn't open, so I couldn't see the problem at the time. Solution apparently is to stop the errant mongo instance - dump its data - and start it again, as if it was a new member of the replica set.

Answer (score 30):

The config is not set correctly.

You can use following command to init:

```
rs.initiate({
      _id: "rs0",
      version: 1,
      members: [
         { _id: 0, host : "localhost:27017" }
      ]
   }
)
```

If you have already initiated, you may get the error msg like me:

```
singleNodeRepl:OTHER> rs.initiate({ _id: "rs0", members: [ { _id: 0, host : "localhost:27017" } ] } )
{
    "info" : "try querying local.system.replset to see current configuration",
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "already initialized",
    "code" : 23,
    "codeName" : "AlreadyInitialized"
}
```

The solution is to `reconf` the mongo:

```
singleNodeRepl:OTHER> rsconf = rs.conf()
singleNodeRepl:OTHER> rsconf.members = [{_id: 0, host: "localhost:27017"}]
[ { "_id" : 0, "host" : "localhost:27017" } ]
singleNodeRepl:OTHER> rs.reconfig(rsconf, {force: true})
{ "ok" : 1 }
singleNodeRepl:OTHER>
singleNodeRepl:SECONDARY>
singleNodeRepl:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: The question involves 3 nodes. But your answer addresses only 1 node.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was able to get my MongoDB docker back up and running after updating!

Answer (score 7):

I was able to replicate the scenario and this is what I got when I did `rs.status()` from the mongod where the command prompt was showing `OTHER`:

```
{
    "state" : 10,
    "stateStr" : "REMOVED",
    "uptime" : 41,
    "optime" : {
        "ts" : Timestamp(1518192445, 1),
        "t" : NumberLong(26)
    },
    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-02-09T16:07:25Z"),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Our replica set config is invalid or we are not a member of it",
    "code" : 93,
    "codeName" : "InvalidReplicaSetConfig",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1518192445, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1518193246, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Let's assume the faulty mongod is the 3rd member (index 2) in the `members` array of the JSON you get when you do `rs.conf()`. Go to your primary and remove the faulty mongod from the replica set:

```
rsconf = rs.conf()
rsconf.members = [rsconf.members[0], rsconf.members[1]] //index 0 and 1 are your working members, we're omitting the 3rd member which is faulty.
rs.reconfig(rsconf);
```

Now restart your mongod that was showing as `OTHER`. And go to your primary again and add the member again. Let's assume the IP is `10.00.00.00` and port is `27019`:

```
rs.add("10.00.00.00:27019")
```

This fixed the issue, and the status changed from OTHER to SECONDARY.

Note that reconf will reset all the client connections. You may need a maintenance window of about a minute to do the reconfigurations.

Comment: At the end, I also needed to do the same `rs.add` command on the member being added since it picked up the config without it as a member after the restart.

Answer (score 0):

change the priority

Let's assume you have the three members

```
rs0:OTHER> cfg = rs.conf()

rs0:OTHER> cfg.members[0].priority = 1

rs0:OTHER> cfg.members[1].priority = 0.5

rs0:OTHER> cfg.members[2].priority = 0.5

rs0:OTHER> rs.reconfig(cfg, {force: true})

rs0:OTHER> rs.config()

rs0:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: Providing some explanation around your answer, will make it more helpful. Also suggest providing what your thinking is.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was : disconnection from robot3t and all mongodb Gui (compass..) used on my pc. then when i reopen the mongo shell it connects as primary.